# Thymeleaf Template Resolves Model Attribute By Escaping Pound Sign In CSS file

Tags: css, spring, templates, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

When I try to load some basic CSS using Thymeleaf into my css file, Thymeleaf does the work but when I use special characters like # and any form of bracket, it gets escaped by \

All I want to do for now is get a HEX Color Value dynamically (In this case a SQL Database) and load it into my CSS file.

NOTE: I am fairly new to Spring MVC as well as Thymeleaf so I might have overlooked a possible solution without knowing it's the solution.

I understand why Thymeleaf feels it should escape these characters because they can be very problematic when it comes to html and xhtml but this is CSS and just need the raw text insert as is.

I have used HTML entities as well as encoding the pound (#) myself but it does not work in CSS and I also feel like this would not be the best solution even if it did:
    HTML Entity (decimal)  #
    HTML Entity (hex)      #

I also took the Javascript route for resolving the template but it does not work for CSS.

CSS Class in my .css file:

```
.bgMainColor{
    background-color:/*[[${styleProperties.Main_Color}]]*/ pink;
}
```

In my JAVA Controller I set the model attribute as follows:

```
model.addAttribute("styleProperties", properties);
```

NOTE: properties contain a list of Style Properties like Main_Color.
Everything in the controller works and Thymeleaf understands when passing the model to the CSS file and the css is inserted but not correctly.

The CSS would then render as:

```
.bgMainColor{
    background-color: \#1BC6B4;
}
```

## 1BC6B4 is the string retrieved from the Database in raw text.

Of coarse this does not work for obvious reasons.

I have searched high and low and could not get a solution that works.
There must be a way to "tell" Thymeleaf that the template being resolved is CSS and not html.

I would be grateful for anyone who has a solution or could point me in the right direction to educate myself as I would do the work myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Thymeleaf is trying to escape your CSS as a CSS identifier.

That being said, you can simply change your expressions from the escaped form `/*[[${...}]]*/` to the unescaped form `/*[(${...})]*/` and it won't escape your color codes.

```
.bgMainColor{
    background-color: /*[(${styleProperties.Main_Color})]*/ pink;
}
```

Comment: Not all heroes where capes! It worked. Very much appreciate the quick answer!